# Jersey Get Headers from Empty Response

Tags: java, rest, post, http-headers, jersey

I'm trying to update part of a legacy codebase I don't fully understand to work with a newer version of a REST API I also don't have access to the internals of. I do have a Swagger instance of it and can invoke it successfully via `curl`, but either Jersey is misbehaving or I'm misunderstanding how to read something.

If I execute the following `curl` command:

```
curl -v -k -X POST "[api endpoint]" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "Authorization: Bearer [jwt token]" -H  "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "sender=[email address]" -F "recipient=[email address]" -F "fileType=file" -F "data=@[file]" -F "metaData=[other file]"
```

I get the following response:

```
> Content-Length: [#]
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------9b1405ed70c2fd40
>
} [5 bytes data]
* We are completely uploaded and fine
{ [5 bytes data]
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 201 Created
< Date: Wed, 26 Aug 2020 00:29:56 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=[ID];Path=/;Secure
< Keep-Alive: timeout=600
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Server: WildFly
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, DELETE, PUT
< Connection: Keep-Alive
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
< Content-Type: application/json
< Location: [value I care about]
< Content-Length: 0
<
100  1667    0     0  100  1667      0   1825 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1825
* Connection #0 to host [proxy] left intact
```

This implies to me that POST responses which have empty bodies but nonempty headers are valid. However, when I try to effect the same thing via Jersey:

```
ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
config.register(MultiPartFeature.class);
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(config);
WebTarget endpoint = client.target([uri]);
FormDataMultiPart post = new FormDataMultiPart()
    .field("sender", [email], MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE)
    .field("recipient", [email], MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE)
    .field("fileType", "file", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE)
    .field("data", [InputStream], MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE)
    .field("metaData", [other InputStream], MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE);
JsonNode response = endpoint.path([api path])
    .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + [jwtTokenString])
    .post(Entity.entity(post, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE), JsonNode.class);
```

I get a `null` response even though I know from inspecting server logs that the API command was received and processed successfully.

After a long time with the debugger I've determined that this is because Jersey will either return a null object or throw an exception if the data is null. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40664884/462291) for more context. Though oddly enough I can't find the section they reference in any of the specification documents I can turn up via Google.)

This is probably fine as I'm not really interested in the empty body of the response, but I can't figure out how to get the HTTP headers returned as a result of my POST in Java.

Comment: Your response is the parsed JSON from the body, so for an empty body, null seems reasonable. You also say "Jersey will either return a null object or throw an exception". Which does it do with the code you've shown us?

Comment: That snippet of code would return null as JaxRSFeature.ALLOW_EMPTY_INPUT isn't set to false. The contextual link provides more info on that behavior which is entirely reasonable now that I know what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the headers because you are using the method to only ask for the body as the response. What you want is the entire [`Response`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/index.html?javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html) object. To get that, leave out the last argument (JsonNode.class) to the `.post()` method. That overloaded method you're using says that you don't care about anything but the body of the response. And that's what you will get.

When you use the overloaded `post()` method without the last body type parameter, the return type will be `Response`. You can get headers from it and the body.

```java
Response response = endpoint.path([api path])
    .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + [jwtTokenString])
    .post(Entity.entity(post, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE));
URI locationUri = response.getLocation();
String locationHeader = response.getHeaderString("Location");
String body = response.readEntity(String.class);
```

Comment: Makes sense when you explain it that way. It's too easy to get tunnel vision when the old codebase supposedly works (though I'd never seen it do so) and I assumed without thinking that the way the new API responded wouldn't be different.

Thanks for catching and coding the value I care about, too.